# issue with CCTouchesBegan

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point1 = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint point2 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    point1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:point1];
    point2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:point2];


    pre = point1;
    curr = point2;
    CCLOG(@"the pre location is %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(pre));
    CCLOG(@"the curr location is %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(curr));


}
```

what wrong with above code? both pre and curr variable gve same output?

Answer (score 1):

When a touch begins, there obviously is no previous touch since the touch has just begun. So both previousLocation and location are the same.

If you run this code in ccTouchesMoved it will work as expected.

Comment: My app has following req: i select a sprite at one point and then I want to move to next touch point

Answer (score 0):

You just have to print your current position in ccTouchesEnded method. it will give you difference between two points.

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

So you just have to get `previousLoaction` in ccTouchesBegan method.